# Add Control for dynamically created Label

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am making a GUI Program which will display some path of files(according to the user input)
Since, the labels are made according to the user input, they are created dynamically. I want that when the user click on the label, the respective file is opened(whose text is displayed).
I have stored all the labels created in a list.
I thought of the following solution to this problem

- Add a  Open function which will Open the file to the Click event

The problem is that
How the function will know which buttons text to use to open the file
 ie
If there are three lables , and user presses 2nd Label how will the Open function know which label is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured out a way

```
    private void LabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Path = ((Label)sender).Text ;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path) ; 
     }
```

Here Path of the file is there in the Label's text property

Answer (score 2):

Give the labels unique names, assign them all the same click event, and use a switch:

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    switch(((Label)sender).Name)
    {
       case "Label1": 
            //........ 
          break;

    }
}
```

Edit:

just subscribe to the event when you create your label:

```
label.Click += label_Click;
```

if you look at the Designer code, that's all it's doing when you set the event in the UI

Comment: But I can only know the no of labels created at runtime. So, how can I use switch

Comment: But how can I use switch when I don't know the no of cases before runtime.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The number of cases doesn't matter once you apply this method

Comment: figured out a way posting it in the form of answers. Anyways, thanks for the help. It was your solution that gave the starting idea.